# Linespace in figure caption

Tags: captions, line-spacing

I have defined my own caption format in my document. It works fine, just as expected. However, there is one Figure where the linespace does not look nice because of the formulas pushing the lines unevenly. How can I fix this caption, without effecting the others?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
\SetAlFnt{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{arg\ min}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\fontsize{8}{0}\selectfont#1#2#3}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{A.pdf} 
\caption{The parameters in $p_{\theta}(x_i|z) \sim \mathcal{N}(\bm{\mu}_{x_i|z}^{}, 
\mathbf{\sigma}_{x_i|z}^2 \mathbf{I})$. 
The reconstruction is given by $\tilde{x}=\bm{\mu}_{x|z}$. For readability 
purposes we do not specify the parameters $\phi,\theta$ in the networks. 
However, these parameters are represented by the lines joining the nodes in 
the networks plus a bias term attached to each node. In the particular case 
of the AEVB algorithm $\phi^{} \equiv \theta^{}$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why this `\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\fontsize{8}{0}\selectfont#1#2#3}` that guarantees uneven linespacing even without the mathematics??????  You are asking for 0pt baselineskip which is not achievable so even a letter with a descender like `g` will change the line spacing, as will a line that has a capital letter

Answer (score 1):

Your general setting was forcing uneven baselineskip (any line with a descender or capital would have more space than a line with lowercase letters such as `axc`). Once that is fixed you can (in this case) hide the depth of the math on the first line with `\smash` but you need to visually check that it does not clash with any tall letters in the line below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\showoutput
%no!!!!\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\fontsize{8}{0}\selectfont#1#2#3}
% \footnotesize is 8pt and you do not want 0pt baselineskip
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\footnotesize#1#2#3}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{A.pdf} 
\caption{The parameters in \smash{$p_{\theta}(x_i|z) \sim \mathcal{N}(\bm{\mu}_{x_i|z}^{}, 
\mathbf{\sigma}_{x_i|z}^2 \mathbf{I})$}. 
The reconstruction is given by $\tilde{x}=\bm{\mu}_{x|z}$. For readability 
purposes we do not specify the parameters $\phi,\theta$ in the networks. 
However, these parameters are represented by the lines joining the nodes in 
the networks plus a bias term attached to each node. In the particular case 
of the AEVB algorithm $\phi^{} \equiv \theta^{}$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I use your code to declare the caption style, the caption size seems to be 10 pt, maybe because i have $\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}$ in my document?

Comment: @user1571823 no it is 8pt I added \showoutput (to check the line space) and that also shows the fonts used which is: .......\glue 2.83337 plus 1.41669 minus 0.94446
.......\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 t
.......\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 h
.......\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 e,, so 8pt computer moder roman.

Comment: Yes you are right. I copy-paste the code in MikTex and there the caption is 8pt, but in ShareLaTex it is 10pt. I may have another command forcing the 10 pt caption, but I dont see what!

Comment: sharelatex if you have just the code above will use 8pt, if you over-ride that with additional code it might do anything, on miktex or sharelatex:-) @user1571823

Comment: I dont do anything with the caption fortmat, except from what I have just shown here, is it any other package that can be causing this problem? I have added all the packages that I used in my original question @David Carslisle

Comment: @user1571823 it uses 8pt with all those packages, if you don't get that add `\showoutput` and ask a new question asking why you do see  `.........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c` (a 10pt c) instead of what I see which is  `.........\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 c` (8pt c) (and similarly for every letter in the caption)